# C# How to Redraw parts of a Form - Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, paint

I'm pretty new to Windows Form, and I am making a 2D Hexagon Grid game, that is starting to get graphical, and slow whenever I re-paint the form, especially on larger maps. I thought if I only re-paint the cells of my game that changed since the last time it was painted, it would paint only afew of the many cells. I didn't realize when you re-paint the form, it clears it before it repaints it, and my game ended up only painting afew of the cells and the rest is just empty space.

FYI, I'm using the Form Paint event, with a nested for loop that draws each cell image and the player pieces image and whatever else the cell needs drawing, so if there are 100 cells, it runs through the paint code 100 times;

Is there a way to not clear the form when re-painting, and just draw over it? Or, can you thing of another way that could potentially speed up painting that isn't extremely complicated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a back-buffer - create a `Bitmap` and draw on that when things change. In the `Paint` event, just `e.Graphics.DrawImage` the bitmap onto the form.

Comment: You set the `DoubleBuffered` property of the form to `true`? If not, that will help. It makes it so the drawing happens in an off-screen buffer and then the presentation is switched to the newly drawn buffer.

Comment: I thought of the back-buffer, I haven't looking into it yet, but it seems plausible to me, and yes, I have double buffer to true.

Comment: Instead of describing, post the code u tried.

Comment: When you call this.Invalidate() you can include a portion of the form as parameter: this.Invalidate(someRegion or someRectangle)..

Comment: I'll look into invalidating certain rectangles, thanks everyone